# C - how to protect a a variable from being accidentally changed after a certain point in the function

Tags: c

C - how to protect a variable from being accidentally changed after a certain point:

For example, in a C program, I declared an integer and changed it's value several times in the first part of the program. But then after a certain point I want to keep its value from being accidentally changed, or at least get a warning when any attempt to change its value happens. How do I do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but maybe put the second part of your function in a subfunction, and pass the variable as a const parameter?  That way at least the compiler will squawk at you change the value.

Comment: for ruby programmers - he needs `Object#taint` or `Object#freeze`

Answer (score 13):

You can't.

A possible solution would be to move the part of the function that modifies the variable into a separate function. That function would return the value of the variable which can be used to initialize a `const` variable:

```
int determine_value_of_a()
{
    int result = 0;
    /* Modifications of result. */
    return result;
}

void f()
{
    const int a = determine_value_of_a();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If using preprocessor macros is acceptable, then you can do this:

```
{ // Function body starts here.
    int x = …;
    … // Change x as desired here.
    const int y = x;
    #define x y;
    … // “x” is actually the const y here.
    #undef x
}
```

Generally, though, I would not recommend it. If you cannot trust the body of a single function to do things correctly, then the function is too complicated and ought to be restructured, as by calling another function to provide the value of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Put the variable in a opaque struct with an indication of whether it can be changed.
Access the variable, both for getting and changing the value, from a function.
If the indication for changeability if off, the function does not allow changes

```
#include "swinger.h"

int main(void) {
    struct moodswinger *var;

    var = newswinger();
    setvar(var, 42);
    getvar(var);
    swing(var, 0);
    setvar(var, -1); /* oops */
}
```

The file `swinger.h` declares the functions.
The file `swinger.c` defines the struct and code.

Answer (score 1):

```
int x;
x = …; // This is okay.
{
    const int y = x; // Make a copy of x.
    {
        const int x = y; // Make a const copy of x that hides the original.
        /*  The compiler should produce a diagnostic if you
            attempt to modify x here.
        */
    }
}
```

Or, if you do not want the indenting to change:

```
int x;
x = …;
{ const int y = x; { const int x = y;
…; // x is const here.
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could do that would be

(a) to use a function to initialize the variable..

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    const int myVar = initMyVar();

    ...
}
```

or (b) pass the variable into another function that does the other work...

```
void myWorkerFunc( const int myVar )
{
    ...
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int myVar = initMyVar();

    ...

    myWorkerFunc( myVar );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a conditional breakpoint on it in your debugger.  Then you will know if it ever changes.  You could also write a "watchdog" type thread that scans your var every so often and warns on change, but that won't be immediate.

Neither of these are within the realm of `C` directly, but would help you determine if your var was erroneously changed.

Comment: BTW, hmjd's response above is probably the best within the language itself.